# Connect google datastore from existing google compute engine in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to connect to Datastore from existing compute engine instance and I'm getting:

> [ python 2.7 - googledatastore-v1beta2_rev1_2.1.0-py2.7 ]
>
> googledatastore.connection.RPCError: commit RPC client failure with HTTP(403) Forbidden: Unauthorized.

the Datastore API is enabled, Permissions is set but GCE is in different zone, one project

what else ?

GCE env:

```
DATASTORE_DATASET = project_id
DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = absolute path to pem file
DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = service_account_email
```

Any tips what should I do/check ? I'm confused because I have exactly the same configuration in my local environment - when I click "play" in pyCharm everything works well ;)

Maybe I missed something...

Thanks for your help  ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a [bug in the Cloud Datastore client library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/37). If you are running on GCE, it will try to use the [scope rules](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_an_existing_cloud_project_with_compute_engine_enabled) and then fail before trying other authentication methods.